# Tons of visual glitches in TechnicPack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

Title: Tons of visual glitches
Version: 7.2.6 | 1.2.5 (Rec)
OS: Windows 7 x64 Professional (java's website says it's Win7 version 6.1)
Java Version: Java SE 7 Update 09

Description of Problem:
So my factory works 100% fine. It's all just visual. I've tried:

- Completely deleting %appdata/.techniclauncher
- Copying the save and saving it as main - copy (worked for a few hours)

It all looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ptXPq.png]

Notice the hitbox is not there and the two chests that are connected to the pipe (the pipe is bending the right way) yet they appear to be way further back.

Image two:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OKkwF.png]

Same thing, showing the chest hitbox. The chests still work, I can right-click them etc...

Image three:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vuImE.png]

The hitbox is a redstone engine. The particle effects are still there and it functions right, but it's not there...

Image four:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rYL5X.png]

This is me standing in the redstone engines that are glitched about ten blocks to the left and about 3 forward. They're not solid. Also only the top 5th of the chest is showing.

Image five:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rAdAs.png]

That's a crystal chest.

14: Emerald
11: Ruby
1: Sapphire
34: Silver ingot

Any ides why it does this?

Also I have a ruby, emeralds, sapphires and silver ingots in other chests and it doesn't glitch out.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the install (after backing up your worlds) and having the launcher reinstall Technic?

Comment: Multiple times.

Comment: You are using the normal texture pack, right?

Comment: @JeffreyLin Yeah, I am.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a graphical bug as opposed to a Java problem.  What graphics chipset are you using, and is the driver up to date?

Comment: TechnicPack have a bug reporting place in their forum: http://forums.technicpack.net/forms/launcher-bug-report.4/respond

Comment: Is this still a problem you're having, or is it specific to this now-obsolete version of Technic?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Way old. I eventually found out that too many crystal chests can cause this.

Comment: Oh cool. Can you make that an answer, even if that brief? (It'll keep the site from regularly auto-bumping it.) I guess IronChests had some bad renderer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found out that too many crystal chests can cause this.

I just replaced them with diamond chests, relogged and problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, one of two things happened:

A. You did not install TechnicPack correctly. Try re-installing it and making sure you are following the directions *exactly*.

B. This is a glitch in TechinicPack. Maybe TechnicPack isn't updated or it's a simple bug.